# Website is up but inaccessible from one IP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns

Asking on behalf of a work colleague. He is trying to reach a website (profiles.interflonusa.com) that he really needs to log into to complete a project. This is a site that I built on WordPress and host on my own server. He was able to hit it from home yesterday morning, but as of yesterday afternoon, despite having changed nothing he can think of, he cannot raise it. The error message he receives is that the server IP cannot be found, even though he can hit other sites on the same server with no problem. The site is a subdomain, and he receives the same error when he tries to hit the main domain (interflonusa.com). He gets the same error on multiple devices, including two laptops and two phones, as long as he is using the same wifi network.

However, the site is up and working fine for everyone else on the planet. And the site is accessible to him on his cell network. It is accessible from a wifi hotspot. I can ping it from terminal. Page speed checkers around the world all show it as up. It is accessible from everywhere. But he cannot raise it when he is using his Comcast/X-finity home network wifi. He has been through three levels of X-finity tech support and had a tech spend two hours at his home today. The tech ran every check he could and replaced the modem. Still can't access this one particular site. The tech and the tech's supervisor are mystified.

I have gone to Siteground support and asked them if for some reason his IP is blocked. It is not. They cannot think of any reason why this might be happening either.

I don't have any rules in .htaccess that might be causing this.

I am using WordFence but the IP is not blocked. There are no blocked IPs in Wordfence at all.

I am using Cloudflare (free version) but the only page rules I have set have to do with https and protecting the login page.

I am officially out of ideas. Does anyone have a suggestion of where to look next?

Comment: Can you please confirm that the site's IP address can be ping'ed from your colleague's network, but that the website is inaccessible when using a DNS/domain name? If so, that suggests this is a DNS issue.

Comment: @SamForbis yes, he could ping it. Turns out adding AAAA records in Cloudflare solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding AAAA (ipv6) records for the domain solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

yea. Looking at the nslookup details, there were IPv6 records showing up for the parent domain, but not for the child domain. Thinking through the chain of support,it's well known that Comcast is pretty aggressive about their adoption of IPv6, so thinking it through, if the web server is serving the content on a default address of `::0` and there is end-to-end support for IPv6, then you should have the AAAA records for the child domain as well.